# Obtain a Bing Session key using Bing Rest services

Tags: bing-maps

I need to do several server 2 server calls to **bing maps rest services**, so I would like to obtain a **session key** using the api key, so I can save on billable calls.
I found samples on how to obtain the session key using ajax sdk or wpf map control, but nothing using directly the rest api making http calls.
Is it possibile to obtaing the session key in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Session keys are only available when using the REST services with one of the interactive map controls. Sessions are an incentive provided to use the interactive Bing Maps controls in a visual application. Sessions cannot be used in server 2 server communications or backend processes.